# Getting a weird error with pass by reference C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm getting this weird error. when I searched more about it, it said that functions weren't defined, but i define it at the bottom of the code. Hopefully someone can help

```
Ld /Users/Bartski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/areaProject-gfmvmiwbtmgqwggbbwbylymlgbvo/Build/Products/Debug/areaProject normal x86_64
cd "/Users/Bartski/Desktop/School/Fall 2014/CIS 265/areaProject"
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta7.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/Bartski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/areaProject-gfmvmiwbtmgqwggbbwbylymlgbvo/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/Bartski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/areaProject-gfmvmiwbtmgqwggbbwbylymlgbvo/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/Bartski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/areaProject-gfmvmiwbtmgqwggbbwbylymlgbvo/Build/Intermediates/areaProject.build/Debug/areaProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/areaProject.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Bartski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/areaProject-gfmvmiwbtmgqwggbbwbylymlgbvo/Build/Intermediates/areaProject.build/Debug/areaProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/areaProject_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Bartski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/areaProject-gfmvmiwbtmgqwggbbwbylymlgbvo/Build/Products/Debug/areaProject

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "circle_area(float&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "square_area(float&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z11square_areaRfS_)
  "rec_area(float&, float&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z8rec_areaRfS_S_)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Source Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

// prototypes of functions

void input_function(float&);
void input_function2(float&, float&);
void output_function(float);
void circle_area(float&);
void square_area(float&);
void rec_area(float&, float&);

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    // initialization of variables

    float input_one;
    float input_two;
    float area;
    int choice;
    char repeat;

    do {
        cout << "please choose which shape you would like to use, 1 for "
                "circle, 2 for square, 3 for rectangle" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        // user chooses which area to calculate

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                cout << "Please enter the radius of the circle" << endl;
                input_function(input_one);
                circle_area(input_one);
                cout << "The area of the circle is " << area << endl;
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "Please enter the lenght of the square side" << endl;
                input_function(input_one);
                square_area(input_one);
                cout << "The area of the square is " << area << endl;
                break;

            case 3:
                cout << "Please enter the lenght of the rectangle height"
                     << endl;
                input_function2(input_one, input_two);
                rec_area(input_one, input_two);
                break;
        }
        cout << "would you like to do it again?  y/n " << endl;
        cin >> repeat;
    } while (repeat ==
             'y'); // repeats if user puts y, ends if anything else is entered

    return 0;
}

// this function gets the input from the user

void input_function2(float& input_one, float& input_two) {
    cout << "please enter the lenght and the width of the rectangle";
    cin >> input_one;
    cin >> input_two;
}

void input_function(float& input_one) {
    cin >> input_one;

    while (input_one < 0) {
        cout << "the dimension cannot be less then 0, please enter again"
             << endl;
        cin >> input_one;
    }
}

// this function calculates the area of the circle

void circle_area(float& input_one, float& area) {
    float const pi = 3.14159;
    area = input_one * input_one * pi;
}

// this function calculates the area of the square

void square_area(float& input_one, float& area) {
    area = input_one * input_one;
}

// this function calculates the area of the rectangle

void rec_area(float& input_one, float& input_two, float& area) {
    area = input_one * input_two;
}

// this function outputs the area to the console

void output_function(float& area) { cout << area; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your functions taking one parameter but then defined them taking two. To the compiler these are two different functions so the linker cannot resolve the reference, hence the error:

Change all the mismatched declarations to take two parameters rather than one.